# How to store an arabic symbol into wchat_t or char32_t?

Tags: c++, encoding, character-encoding, arabic

Compiler: `clang 3.5.0`

The following code works as far as I expected:

```
#include <iostream>

char cp[] = "ي";

int main()
{
    std::cout << cp; //Prints ي
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8971727d905eec8)**

But if we try to store that symbol into `char32_t` or `wchar_t` we've got an error:

```
#include <iostream>

wchar_t t = 'ي'; //character too large for enclosing character literal type

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45331f499b5c3cb8)**

Is it possible to store such symbols into a `wchar_t` or `char32_t` object? I suspect it depends on a particular compiler and OS I'm using.

Comment: Do mention your compiler.  Try wchar_t t = L'ي';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `L"ي"` to put it in `wchar_t`, and later print it out using `std::wcout`:
2. Use `U"ي"` to put it in `char32_t`, and later print it out using `std::wcout` after being cast by `wchar_t`:

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   wchar_t cp[] = L"ي"; 
   char32_t cp2[] = U"ي";

   int main()
   {
       std::wcout << cp; // Prints ي
       std::wcout << (wchar_t) cp2; // Prints ي
   }
   ```

PS: This doesn't work if you are trying to write text that cannot be represented in your default locale.